# How to configure AWS load balancer to forward to external IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I currently have multiple instances of the same web application running on different instances by different vendors (AWS, Digital Ocean, Vultr). Each application instance run on their own port numbers.

I wish to configure AWS Applilcation/Network Load Balancer such that it will forward the requests to these endpoints:

Client -- HTTP Request --> Domain Name --> AWS Load Balancing Endpoint (IP Address?) --> Load Balancer rules --> Instances on AWS / Digital Ocean / Vultr.

Is there a way to do the above?

Answer (score 5):

AWS Application Load Balancer’s *Target Group* can have either *EC2 instance* or *IP address* targets. In your case you need to use the *IP address* targets.

Here are the instructions: **[Application Load Balancing to IP Address](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancing-via-ip-address-to-aws-on-premises-resources/)**

> These addresses can be in the same VPC as the ALB, a peer VPC in the same region, on an EC2 instance connected to a VPC by way of ClassicLink, or on on-premises resources at the other end of a VPN connection or AWS Direct Connect connection.

Comment: "Minor" detail: you also need VPNs for this to work.  *"Application Load Balancers can now route traffic directly to IP addresses. These addresses can be in the same VPC as the ALB, a peer VPC in the same region, on an EC2 instance connected to a VPC by way of ClassicLink, or on on-premises resources at the other end of a VPN connection or AWS Direct Connect connection."*  ALBs can't route to arbitrary destinations on the Internet.

Comment: Note also that, for targets located outside the load balancer’s VPC, "You can use... any IPv4 address from the RFC 1918 ranges (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, and 192.168.0.0/16) or the RFC 6598 range (100.64.0.0/10)"

Comment: How add ip to aws LB, in case the IPs are dynamic ?

Comment: Yes, most sites are dynamic IP, so would be best to fwd to a DNS name.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 4):

Alternative is to use a Lambda target on the Application Load Balancer, and have the Lambda proxy the requests through to your external IP.

Or an EC2 / ECS hosted proxy.